# Counting the maximum lines that can fit in an android edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I created a code that I thing that it will return me the number of lines that can fit in an android edittext, but not works fine. The code is inside a TextWatcher of an editext.

My code is:

```
Math.round((dpFromPx(edittext.getHeight())-67)/spFromPx(edittext.getTextSize()))
```

The `-67` is the sum of the margins in dp that this edittext have in the top and in the bottom.

The methods used are for converting px to dp and px to sp are the following

```
private float dpFromPx(float px){
    return px / this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}
public float spFromPx(Float px) {
    float scaledDensity = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    return px/scaledDensity;
}
```

I think that code should tell me the maximum lines that can fit in an edittext but always return me anumber that are more lines that the lines that can fit in an edittext.

So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that the code that is more correct is the following:

```
Math.round((dpFromPx(edittext.getHeight())-67)/spFromPx(edittext.getTextSize()))-3
```

Is the same as the first, but this has a -3 that adjust some rare things that I couldn't understand.